# How to open a TCP Stream and send multiple messages between POS machine and an App?

Tags: c#, tcp, stream, tcpclient, pos

I have a problem with the communication with a POS machine.
I have made a WinForms App that communicates with a POS.
The below code is what what I have done so far :

> First I send the message to the POS and I get a response from it but then if , after some seconds , the POS wants to send me another one response I can not get it.

How can I make the code to be able to communicate with the POS and send between them a lot of messages?

**For example:**

> If a person make a purchase , the POS get the data and responses accordingly but when the person touch his / her card to pay , I can get that response from the POS despite the fact , that the purchase proceeds without any problem.

```
string IP = "xxx.xxx.xx.xx";
int port = 45000;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IP , port);

string message = "test";
byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
stream.Write(message, 0, message.Length);

data = new Byte[1024];
String response = String.Empty;

int bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
```

Comment: If POS can send messages at any time, then you need to spawn a thread that listens permanently. And therefore send and receive on different threads. Thus, if you have messages App->POS that trigger an answer, you need to find a way to match "request/response" _and_ be able to handle incoming messages that have no request from app.

Comment: @Fildor , thank you for your comment , could you provide me with some code for this?

Comment: That's a little too much for an SO answer, I am afraid. I think you'll be able to find examples if you look for "multithreaded TCP Service C#" or something alike. It's also hard to give an example, because we don't know your message format and if / how it is possible to match request and response.

Comment: On first attempt I found these top hits: https://codinginfinite.com/multi-threaded-tcp-server-core-example-csharp/ , https://www.codeproject.com/articles/2866/multi-threaded-net-tcp-server-examples. I don't think they are copy&paste production ready, but you should get an idea of how you want to have it look like.